# Linking Two Event emissions

Tags: solidity, tokens

If I have a (NFT) token that has a TransferSingle event emitted when the token is transferred, and I emit a second event that indicates it was a sale at a certain price--how do I link the sale to the transfer? There could be multiple sales/transfers in a single transaction. Is it sufficient to query sale events from the same block and match by the other parameters (to, from, nft id?)

I am obligated by ERC-1155 to emit a specifically formed TransferSingle event so I can't just bolt them together in a new event type.

Answer (score 0):

You can emit a new event with the required information

```
event TransferWithPrice(address sender, address recipient, uint tokenId, uint price);
```